# AWS API Gateway/Lambda/DynamoDB - .get_item() not finding item in table

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I currently have POSTed items into the DynamoDB (the date is a string):
[dynamodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5EN1.png)

When I try accessing this via a GET, I get 404 not found (not a 502 so it appears the lambda response is OK):
[get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYrW.png)

This is the code in my lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info(event)
    httpMethod = event['httpMethod']
    path = event['path']
    
    if httpMethod == getMethod and path == answersPath:
        response = buildResponse(200)
    elif httpMethod == getMethod and path == dailyAnswerPath:
        response = getAnswer(event['queryStringParameters']['day'])
    else:
        response = buildResponse(404, 'Not Found')
        
        
    return response
        
def getAnswer(day):
    try:
        response = table.get_item(
            Key = {
                'day': day
            }    
        )
        if 'answer' in response:
            return buildResponse(200, response['answer'])
        else:
            return buildResponse(404, {'Message':'Day %s not found' %day})
    except:
        logger.exception('getAnswer error day %s' %day)

def buildResponse(statusCode, body=None):
    response = {
        'statusCode': statusCode,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
        }
    }
    if body is not None:
        response['body'] = json.dumps(body, cls=encodeddd)
    return response
```

Comment: Are you getting 404 "Not Found", or 404 "Day %s not found"?

Comment: I'm getting 404 "Day %s not found"